# Openedx deployed locally

Tags: openedx

After installing and deploying OpenEdx through tutor, I ran Openedx deployed locally and accessed the customized LMS and CMS domain names, and found the following situation. May I ask if my installation and deployment is correct? If so, may I ask what I should do next? If not, what went wrong? f Thank you very much for your answer[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGaa9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwwLc.png)

Since I have no experience at all, please tell me what I should do next